# Wifi disabled in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, network-adapter, lenovo-laptop, wireless-adapter

Every time i turn on my laptop, wifi is disabled. It takes a restart to make it work.
I have tried reinstalling wifi drivers, read articles, even reinstalled windows but it didn't help.
Lenovo Z500 laptop, windows 10 ver1903

Comment: Do you have Airplane Mode enabled? Disable Airplane Mode.  Is there a function key on your keyboard for Wi-Fi (yes, there should be) . Make sure that is not toggled OFF.

Comment: Yes airplane mode is disabled but there's no function key to enable wifi

Comment: Try Fn-F5 to enable / disable Wireless.   "Method One - Fn+F5
Press Fn+F5 (or F5). The Lenovo Wireless Device Settings window will show. ...
On the Lenovo Wireless Device Settings window, set Wireless Network Card On to enable the WiFi, off to disable it."

Comment: I tried, but this function key just refreshes the page

Comment: Use Lenovo Update (in your Control Panel) and update ALL drivers including BIOS and then restart.

Comment: One other (stupid) Q.  Do you possibly have an Ethernet cable plugged in?

Comment: No i haven't.and the intresting thing is that i have tried using Ethernet port several times before, but it is disable too!